# How to compile RootCloak Plus APK from Github source?

Tags: android, android-studio, cydia-substrate

[source code](https://github.com/devadvance/rootcloakplus)

I've tried importing it to Android Studio directly from GitHub, I've tried importing it from extracted zip and migrating to Gradle project. Both times I got `Error:(22, 28) java: package com.saurik.substrate does not exist`.

I have downloaded Cydia Substrate API following [this guide](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/id/73e45fe5-4525-4de7-ac14-6016652cc1b8/) but it still doesn't work.

Can anybody help me compile APK from that source?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [cydia_substrate-r2.zip](http://asdk.cydiasubstrate.com/zips/cydia_substrate-r2.zip) and copy the substrate-api.jar into rootcloakplus-master -> app -> libs folder. Right click on substrate-api.jar and click 'Add as Library...' .

Done.